# String equality returning false when strings are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor element :

```
<a id="buyBtn" href="#" alt="Purchase" title="Buy now" data-enabled="true">
```

When it is clicked, I'm doing this:

```
enabled = $(this).data('enabled') == "true";
console.log(enabled);
```

However, the console shows `false`. I was initially using `===` but that was giving false, so I moved to `==`.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log($(this).data('enabled'))`?

Comment: Working example showing what's at play here: http://jsfiddle.net/FsP3j/1/

Comment: @Cthulhu - The issue, in reality, is the OP did `=== "true"` instead of `=== true`. Face, meet palm, doh si doh.

Comment: @Cthulhu: That's not the issue at hand. The issue was that jquery automatically converts the string 'true' to boolean `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accepted answer for this question details why:

[Retrieve boolean data from data attribute in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921076/retrieve-boolean-data-from-data-attribute-in-jquery)

jQuery's `.data()` method is smart enough to convert "true"/"false" data strings into real Boolean values.

The strict comparison operator checks types, and is failing because you are comparing a string to a boolean.

```
"true" === true // false
```

Comment: oh, wow...sheesh. I would never have guessed that. Thank you.