# Razor boolean html5 attribute being capitalised prevented conditional statements in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have a razor view with:

```
<select id="roletypeddl" >
   <option value="@roletype.Id" selected="selected" data-assignabletoperson="@roletype.AssignableToPerson" >@roletype.Name</option>
</select>
```

So in jquery I wanted to run some code if data-assignabletoperson was true hence:

```
if ($('#roletypeddl').find('option:selected').data('assignabletoperson') == true)
{
  do something
}
```

Trouble is this code is never getting executed.

I figure it has to do with the html being produced being:

```
<select id="roletypeddl">
  <option data-assignabletoperson="True" selected="selected" value="5">Manufacturer</option>
</select>
```

I think the problem is that the "True" is capitalised. Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-` attribute does not know your data type. `@roletype.AssignableToPerson` html output is `True`, but this is not bool value, this is string...

following statement

```
data-assignabletoperson="True"
```

is not bool value, its string, So you should compare like this:

```
if ($('#roletypeddl').find('option:selected').data('assignabletoperson') == "True")
{
    do something
}
```

**Update:** `data` knows your data type. Problem is the "True". It must be "true".

And the [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6BA8t/)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense and works. Strange because the correct answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921076/retrieve-boolean-data-from-data-attribute-in-jquery seems to disagree with this and says data() can handle boolean data?

Comment: Yes. I saw it, you right. Answer is your suggestion `I think the problem is that the "True" is capitalised`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
data-assignabletoperson="@roletype.AssignableToPerson.ToLower()"
```

Eg.

```
<select id="roletypeddl" >
   <option value="@roletype.Id" selected="selected" data-assignabletoperson="@roletype.AssignableToPerson.ToLower()" >@roletype.Name</option>
</select>
```

Refer:

[Why does Boolean.ToString output “True” and not “true”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491334/why-does-boolean-tostring-output-true-and-not-true)

Also, You can use javascript:

**[.toLowerCase()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp)**

Eg.:

```
if ($('#roletypeddl').find('option:selected').data('assignabletoperson').toLowerCase() == 'true')
{
  //do something
}
```