# jQuery .data() does not return boolean value; why?

Tags: jquery

I'm very unexperienced jQuery programmer unable to find a bug in my trivial script. Could you please help?

I want to emphasize a checkbox if its state differs from the initial value. That initial value is stored as `data-init` attribute. The generated html for checked and unchecked input looks like this:

```
<td><input checked data-init id="controls-0-modeU" name="controls-0-modeU" type="checkbox" value="y"></td>

<td><input id="controls-1-modeU" name="controls-1-modeU" type="checkbox" value="y"></td>
```

In the accepted answer here: [Retrieve boolean data from data attribute in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921076/retrieve-boolean-data-from-data-attribute-in-jquery) there is: "*The jQuery `.data()` method is smart about recognizing boolean and numeric values and converts them into their native type*". That is what I want.

My script begins with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("td input:checkbox").change(function(){
            var $init = $(this).data("init")
```

But the value of `$init` is either `undefined` (for initially unchecked input) or an empty string (for initially checked). Both of them evaluate to false. Why am I not getting true/false instead?

Comment: There's no `data-init` attribute on the check box...

Comment: and there are multiple check-boxes and your code is incomplete.

Comment: Your `data-init` didn't have any value. Just an empty attribute for `checked` checkbox? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried `data-init="false"`? Your attribute is in fact empty

Comment: What I know `$(this).data("init")` will give string ("true"/"false"). But `$(this).attr("data-init")` will give boolean values.

Comment: The html5 standard says: "_The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value._" (section 3.2.2)

Comment: @VPfB yes but `data` is a custom attribute-set which can contain anything. It's not a boolean attribute, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/707702/4202224)

Comment: @empiric This means I cannot select the type. Thank you for correcting my wrong understanding of it. I will use two distinct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data attribute is not treated like a boolean attribute by jQuery(like checked, readonly, etc) so you have to give it a value

```
<td><input checked data-init="true" id="controls-0-modeU" name="controls-0-modeU" type="checkbox" value="y"></td>

<td><input  data-init="false" id="controls-1-modeU" name="controls-1-modeU" type="checkbox" value="y"></td>
```

if you want to keep your mark up you'll have to do the heavy lifting yourself

```
var $init = $(this).is("[data-init]");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the element has the attribute like so:

```
if (!!$(this).attr("data-init")) {
  // its there
}
else {
  // its not
}
```

Comment: `!!` but why? Despite that, his attribute is in fact empty and doesn't contain a boolean value

Comment: because a missing attribute can return `undefined` or `false`, this way you can catch both as "falsy" values

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP wants especially with the linked answer in mind. He is not asking about checking the value he gets but rather on why he is not getting the expected value